# Select 50 items from list at random

Tags: python, list, select, random

I have a function which reads a list of items from a file. How can I select only 50 items from the list randomly to write to another file?

```
def randomizer(input, output='random.txt'):
    query = open(input).read().split()
    out_file = open(output, 'w')
    
    random.shuffle(query)
    
    for item in query:
        out_file.write(item + '\n')
```

For example, if the total randomization file was

```
random_total = ['9', '2', '3', '1', '5', '6', '8', '7', '0', '4']
```

and I would want a random set of 3, the result could be

```
random = ['9', '2', '3']
```

How can I select 50 from the list that I randomized?

Even better, how could I select 50 at random from the original list?

Answer (score 400, accepted):

If the list is in random order, you can just take the first 50.

Otherwise, use

```
import random
random.sample(the_list, 50)
```

`random.sample` help text:

```
sample(self, population, k) method of random.Random instance
    Chooses k unique random elements from a population sequence.
    
    Returns a new list containing elements from the population while
    leaving the original population unchanged.  The resulting list is
    in selection order so that all sub-slices will also be valid random
    samples.  This allows raffle winners (the sample) to be partitioned
    into grand prize and second place winners (the subslices).
    
    Members of the population need not be hashable or unique.  If the
    population contains repeats, then each occurrence is a possible
    selection in the sample.
    
    To choose a sample in a range of integers, use xrange as an argument.
    This is especially fast and space efficient for sampling from a
    large population:   sample(xrange(10000000), 60)
```

Comment: Can I have `random.sample` return also the indices it has chosen?

Comment: Make it sample from a list of indices (range(len(list)) then reconstruct the sample from the list of random indices and the original list.

Answer (score 52):

One easy way to select random items is to shuffle then slice.

```
import random
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
random.shuffle(a)
print a[:4] # prints 4 random variables
```

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck Why would random shuffling and slicing be better? Wouldn't selecting a number of sample by randomizing the selection have the same merits as random shuffling and then taking a slice of the shuffled samples? Can you please explain? Thanks.

Comment: I used this to easily create a test / train set for a machine learning project. Using `random.choice(mylist,3)` wouldn't create two disjoint sets as this did.

Answer (score 47):

I think `random.choice()` is a better option.

```
import numpy as np

mylist = [13,23,14,52,6,23]

np.random.choice(mylist, 3, replace=False)
```

the function returns an array of 3 randomly chosen values from the list

Comment: I think you need to use `random.choice(mylist, 3, replace=False)`. Also less confusing to use `import numpy as np` and `np.random.choice(mylist, 3, replace=False)`

Comment: This is has chances of repeating the list item

Comment: No this is not a better option, it is ~100 times slower

Answer (score 3):

1. we have 3 samples ('orange','mango','apple'). Created series, should contain 7 elements & randomly selected from list.

   ###### random.choice

   ```py
   import random

   import numpy as np

   fruits = ['orange','mango','apple']

   np.random.choice(fruits, 7, replace=True)
   ```

   **Output**

   ```py
   array(['orange', 'mango', 'apple', 'orange', 'orange', 'mango', 'apple'],
         dtype='<U6')
   ```
2. Random selection from list (less than 3 values)

   ###### random.sample

   ```py
   import random

   random.sample(fruits, 3)
   ```

Answer (score -4):

Say your list has 100 elements and you want to pick 50 of them in a random way. Here are the steps  to follow:

1. Import the libraries
2. Create the seed for random number generator, I have put it at 2
3. Prepare a list of numbers from which to pick up in a random way
4. Make the random choices from the numbers list

**Code:**

```
from random import seed
from random import choice

seed(2)
numbers = [i for i in range(100)]

print(numbers)

for _ in range(50):
    selection = choice(numbers)
    print(selection)
```