# Is it possible to create a list consisting of a percentage of elements of another list?

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to create a dependency parser from a corpus. The corpus is in conll format so I have a function that reads the files and return a list of lists, in which each list is a parsed sentence (the corpus I'm using is already parsed, my job is to find another alternative in this parse). My professor asked to randomly pick only the 5% of sentences in this corpus, as it is too large.

I have tried creating an empty list and use the append function, but I don't know how can I specify by indexing that I want 5 out of each 100 sentences of the corpus

The function I have made for converting the conll files is the following:

```
import os, nltk, glob
def read_files(path):
    """
    Function to load Ancora Dependency corpora (GLICOM style)
    path = full path to the files
    returns de corpus in sentences
        each sentence is a list of tuples
            each tuple is a token with the follwoing info:
                index of the token in the sentence
                token
                lemma
                POS /es pot eliminar
                POS
                FEAT /es pot eliminar
                head
                DepRelation
    """
    corpus = []
    for f in glob.glob(path):
        sents1 = open(f).read()[185:-2].split('\n\n')
        sents2 = []
        for n in range(len(sents1)):
            sents2.append(sents1[n].split('\n'))
        sents3 = []
        for s in sents2:
            sent = []
            for t in s:
                sent.append(tuple(t.split('\t')))
            sents3.append(sent)
        corpus.extend(sents3)
    return corpus
```

I want a way of selecting 5 sentences of every 100 in the corpus so I can have a list of lists containing only these.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show sample input data and expected result?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select 50 items from list at random to write to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511349/select-50-items-from-list-at-random-to-write-to-file)

Comment: random.sample(the_list, 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you add a loop for appending the list? So something like this which uses the modulus operator "%" which will only get 5 out of 100 sentences:

```
counter = 0
new_list =[]
for i in my_list:
  counter = counter +1 
  if counter % 20 ==0:
       new_list.append(i)
  else:
       continue
```

Comment: i am probably doing something wrong, i added that to my loop and i get this type error: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

Comment: I don't know why that is happening. I'm guessing it's something to do with the input list format? Playing around I can't recreate that error. Are you doing something like this somewhere: `[list_1] +[list_2]` if so that may be it

Comment: in the code you wrote i changed my_list for corpus, which is the name of the variable for my list. The rest i copied in the definition of my function. Tomorrow i will ask my teacher and i can tell you what was my mistake

Comment: OK, Having looked at the code above I believe the problem will be coming form the `corpus.extend(sents3)` maybe try `corpus.append(sents3)` instead?
There is a difference for how python handles `extend` and `append`
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/difference-between-append-vs-extend-list-methods-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Just use `random.sample`:

```
# define path here
corpus = read_files(path)

random.sample(corpus, len(corpus) // 20)
```