# How to randomly select two elements of a python list?

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
mylist = ['a','b','c','d']
```

How can I index the list so that I choose only two of the four elements? `mylist[]` throws all sorts of errors depending what datatype I put in the square brackets for indexing

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/random.html#random.choices

Comment: This is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511349/select-50-items-from-list-at-random-to-write-to-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `random.sample` Try this:

```python
import random
mylist = ['a','b','c','d']

print(random.sample(mylist, 2))
```

Comment: How can I also randomly select two columns from an N-column numpy array? and pandas dataframe?